# AJAX autocomplete does not work

Tags: c#, asp.net, autocomplete, webforms, asp.net-ajax

I'm trying to create a simple screen with ASP.NET using AJAX for auto complete text from textbox.

This is my ASPX code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Pages/MasterPageHeader.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MainPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="UBTechSite.Pages.MainPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainPage" runat="server">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../JSCode/MainPageJS.js"></script>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" Text="Find Person" ForeColor="Gray" runat="server" onfocus="ClearWaterMark(this);" onblur="CreatWaterMark(this);"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Search" />
</asp:Content>
```

This is my MainPageJS.js file code:

```
function ClearWaterMark(ctrl) {
    if (ctrl.value == "Find Person") {
        ctrl.value = "";
        ctrl.style.color = "black";
    }
}

function CreatWaterMark(ctrl) {
    if (ctrl.value.length == 0) {
        ctrl.value = "Find Person";
        ctrl.style.color = "gray";
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    SearchPerson();
});

function SearchPerson() {
    $("#txtSearch").autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "MainPage.aspx/GetPeopleByName",
                data: '{name: "' + $("input[id$=txtSearch]").val() + '" }',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("No Match");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

In my cs file I have a function name GetPeopleByName with the property of [WebMethod].

My problem is that nothing happens when I type something in the textbox.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.

I'm using now AjaxControlToolkit and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this http://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/. :) It's so easy to implement. In your controller, just create a JsonResult method.